# React Starter Kit - cannot make API requests in production

Tags: reactjs, react-starter-kit

I have a custom API endpoint that makes a request to instagram to download an instagram page's JSON and then render posts.

this works in development, however, in production I get the error

`POST https://my-heroku-siteURL.herokuapp.com/api/instagram 503 (Service Unavailable)`

I am curious about how to debug this? I cannot replicate when I run a production build in my local server

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to tell you what the problem might be. What are you actually serving in production? Are you using a proxy locally? Is that configuration replicated when deployed?

Comment: the url looks odd, are you sure you should replace "site" with your site name?